# Disabled button condition based on radio button using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Currently when I have not checked any radio, the button will be disabled. When I check one of the parent radio (eg `Parent 1`), the button is still disabled, but when I check one of the children of the parent radio, the disabled attribute will be removed.

But when I try to check `Parent 2`, the button is still active and not disabled.

What I want is when the parent radio is checked, the button will be disabled. However, when selecting the child radio in the checked parent radio, the disable attribute will be removed

```js
$('.checkbox-child').on('click', function(){
   $('.submit-button').removeAttr('disabled')
});
```

```css
.submit-button{
  background-color:red;
  border:none;
  padding:10px 20px;
  color:white;
}

.submit-button:disabled{
  background-color: grey !important;
}

.checkbox-child-wrapper{
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="checkbox-container">
  <div class="item-container" id="parent-1">
    <input type="radio" name="check-parent" class="checkbox-parent"> Parent 1
    <div class="checkbox-child-wrapper">
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox-child"> Child 1
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox-child"> Child 2
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox-child"> Child 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-container" id="parent-2">
    <input type="radio" name="check-parent" class="checkbox-parent"> Parent 2
    <div class="checkbox-child-wrapper">
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox-child"> Child 1
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox-child"> Child 2
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox-child"> Child 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="submit-button" disabled>Submit</button>
```

Comment: If parent is 1 checked and children checkbox of parent 2 is selected then also button is disabled? If directly first child is selected then its parent is selected then button will be enabled? Its not mandatory that the user should select parent first then its child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as below snippet:

```js
$('.checkbox').on('click', function(){
  debugger;
  if ($(this).hasClass('parent')) {
    $('.submit-button').prop('disabled', true);
    $('.child').attr('checked', false);
  } else {
    $('.submit-button').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

```css
.submit-button{
  background-color:red;
  border:none;
  padding:10px 20px;
  color:white;
}

.submit-button:disabled{
  background-color: grey !important;
}

.checkbox-child-wrapper{
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="checkbox-container">
  <div class="item-container" id="parent-1">
    <input type="radio" name="check-parent" class="checkbox parent"> Parent 1
    <div class="checkbox-child-wrapper">
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox child"> Child 1
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox child"> Child 2
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox child"> Child 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-container" id="parent-2">
    <input type="radio" name="check-parent" class="checkbox parent"> Parent 2
    <div class="checkbox-child-wrapper">
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox child"> Child 1
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox child"> Child 2
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox child"> Child 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="submit-button" disabled>Submit</button>
```

Comment: This still enables the Submit button when you select Parent 1 and Child 2 of Parent 2. Not sure if OP wants that behavior.

Comment: If you want to avoid that behaviour, it is another question. What I provide is the solution for the problem OP was facing at the time.

Comment: @kmoser ya i just need this for parent.  i've solved the issue that kmoser told

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to enable the Submit button only when a parent and one of its child radio buttons are checked.

```js
$('.checkbox-parent').on('click', function() {
    // If at least one checked child, enable submit, else disable submit:
    if ( $(this).next().find('input:checked').length ) {
       $('.submit-button').removeAttr('disabled')
   } else {
       $('.submit-button').attr('disabled', true)
   }
});

$('.checkbox-child').on('click', function(){
    // If parent is checked, enable submit, else disable submit:
    if ( $(this).parent().previous().attr('checked') ) {
        $('.submit-button').removeAttr('disabled')
    } else {
        $('.submit-button').attr('disabled', true)
    }
});
```

```css
.submit-button{
  background-color:red;
  border:none;
  padding:10px 20px;
  color:white;
}

.submit-button:disabled{
  background-color: grey !important;
}

.checkbox-child-wrapper{
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="checkbox-container">
  <div class="item-container" id="parent-1">
    <input type="radio" name="check-parent" class="checkbox-parent"> Parent 1
    <div class="checkbox-child-wrapper">
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox-child"> Child 1
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox-child"> Child 2
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox-child"> Child 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-container" id="parent-2">
    <input type="radio" name="check-parent" class="checkbox-parent"> Parent 2
    <div class="checkbox-child-wrapper">
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox-child"> Child 1
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox-child"> Child 2
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox-child"> Child 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="submit-button" disabled>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".item-container").click(function(event) {
    const parentcheckbox = $(this).children()[0]; // checkbox-parent
    const checkboxWrapper = $(this).children()[1]; // checkbox-child-wrapper
    const childCheckBoxes = $(checkboxWrapper).children(); // all checkbox-child
  
    if($(parentcheckbox).is(':checked')){ // iterate only if parent is checked
        let isChildChecked = false;
        childCheckBoxes.each(function( index ) {
            // console.log($(childCheckBoxes[index] ).is(':checked'));
            if($(childCheckBoxes[index] ).is(':checked')){ // if any child is checked then enable button
                isChildChecked = true;
                return false; // break out of loop
            }
        });
    
        isChildChecked ? $("#submit-button").removeAttr("disabled") : $(".submit-button").attr("disabled", true);
    
    }else{
        $(".submit-button").attr("disabled", true); // if parent is unchecked disable button
    }
});
```

```css
.submit-button{
  background-color:red;
  border:none;
  padding:10px 20px;
  color:white;
}

.submit-button:disabled{
  background-color: grey !important;
}

.checkbox-child-wrapper{
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox-container">
  <div class="item-container" >
    <input type="radio" name="check-parent" class="checkbox-parent"> Parent 1
    <div class="checkbox-child-wrapper">
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox-child"> Child 1
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox-child"> Child 2
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox-child"> Child 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-container" >
    <input type="radio" name="check-parent" class="checkbox-parent"> Parent 2
    <div class="checkbox-child-wrapper">
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox-child"> Child 1
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox-child"> Child 2
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox-child"> Child 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-container" >
    <input type="radio" name="check-parent" class="checkbox-parent"> Parent 3
    <div class="checkbox-child-wrapper">
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox-child"> Child 1
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox-child"> Child 2
      <input type="radio" name="check-child" class="checkbox-child"> Child 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="submit-button" id="submit-button" disabled>Submit</button>
```

Comment: Code will still work if you have additional any number of same parent-child checkboxes